# AttributeError: type object 'Employee' has no attribute 'set_raise_amt' in python

Tags: python

I am not sure why I am getting this error in python:

```
class Employee:
    raise_amount = 15
    num_of_emps = 0
    def __init__(self,first,last,pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay
        self.email = self.first+'.'+self.last+'@gmail.com'

        Employee.num_of_emps +=1

    def fullname(self):
        return '{}{}'.format(self.first,self.last)


    def apply_raise(self):
        self.pay = int(self.pay * self.raise_amount)

@classmethod
def set_raise_amt(cls,amount):
    cls.raise_amt=amount



emp1 = Employee('Tanush','Singh',60000)
emp2 = Employee('Manush','Singh',40000)
emp3 = Employee('Darshan','Dave',80000)
emp4 = Employee('Ravi','Teja',55000)

print(emp1.fullname())
print(emp1.pay)
print(Employee.num_of_emps)
emp1.apply_raise()
print(emp1.pay)
Employee.set_raise_amt(20)
print(emp1.raise_amt())
```

The error that I am getting after adding the decorator:

```
 Error: AttributeError: type object 'Employee' has no attribute 'set_raise_amt'
```

Comment: Indentation Error. Move the method inside the class

Comment: Also remove paranthesis of `emp1.raise_amt()` in the last line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their is Indentation problem in you code. The function set_raise_amt() is outside the class. That's why when you are trying to access it using Employee.set_raise_amt(30) it is giving you error, as set_raise_amt() is not the part of class Employee.
Summary : Correct the **indentation**, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Define your class method inside your class, the same as you would any other method. (indent it)